# assign elements of a list to several keys while preventing those keys to have the same value

Tags: clojure

I'm a beginner and trying to generate several keys out of the clojure script to make a quiz on movie categories.
Each question has several options with only one being right.

Two main problems I'm stuck on:

1. randomly generate a list of questions and possible answers while preventing the answer options from having the same value
2. making sure the right pair value of keys and values (example: (`:mov` `"Jumanji"`) & (`:correct` `"Comedy"`)

some description

- `:mov` is movie title
- `:categ` is category of the movie
- `:wrong1` is wrong answer 1

my current code. (the list was made shorter for conciseness)

```clj
(defn movies
  []
  ["Jumanji" "Transporter" "Titanic" "Spongebob"])

(defn category
  []
  ["Comedy" "Action" "Drama" "Cartoon"])

(defn movie_quizz
  []
  (let [mov (movies)
        categ (category)]
    (->> (for [mov categ]
           {:question mov :correct categ
            :wrong1 (rand-nth (remove #{:correct} categ))
            :wrong2 (rand-nth (remove #{:correct :wrong1} categ))
            :wrong3 (rand-nth (remove #{:correct :wrong1 :wrong2} categ)})))
    shuffle (take 30)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do it.  I lay out the solution in small steps.  It is based on [this template project](https://github.com/io-tupelo/clj-template).

```clj
(ns tst.demo.core
  (:use tupelo.core tupelo.test)
  (:require
    [clojure.set :as set]
  ))

(defn rand-question
  []
  (let [movies          {"Jumanji"     "Comedy"
                         "Transporter" "Action"
                         "Titanic"     "Drama"
                         "Spongebob"   "Cartoon"}
        N               3
        movie-entries   (vec movies) ; a vector of pairs [<key> <value>]
        movie-entries-rand (shuffle movie-entries) ; random order now
        movie-target   (first movie-entries-rand) ; a random [key val] pair
        movie-title     (first movie-target)
        movie-cat-correct (second movie-target)

        cats-all        (set (mapv second movies)) ; all categories as a set (no dups)
        cats-no-correct (set/difference cats-all #{movie-cat-correct})
        cats-wrong      (take (dec N) (shuffle cats-no-correct))

        cat-choices-all (shuffle (conj cats-wrong movie-cat-correct))]
    (newline)
    (println "Pick the correct category for this movie:  " movie-title)
    (println cat-choices-all)))

(dotest
  (dotimes [i 10]
    (rand-question))
)
```

with result

```sh
-----------------------------------
   Clojure 1.10.3    Java 15.0.2
-----------------------------------

Testing tst.demo.core

Pick the correct category for this movie:   Transporter
[Cartoon Drama Action]

Pick the correct category for this movie:   Spongebob
[Cartoon Action Comedy]

Pick the correct category for this movie:   Spongebob
[Drama Action Cartoon]

Pick the correct category for this movie:   Jumanji
[Comedy Action Cartoon]

Pick the correct category for this movie:   Spongebob
[Action Cartoon Comedy]

Pick the correct category for this movie:   Jumanji
[Drama Cartoon Comedy]

Pick the correct category for this movie:   Jumanji
[Cartoon Comedy Action]

Pick the correct category for this movie:   Titanic
[Comedy Action Drama]

Pick the correct category for this movie:   Transporter
[Action Cartoon Drama]

Pick the correct category for this movie:   Titanic
[Comedy Action Drama]
```

Note that you can change the `let` to `let-spy` to see the intermediate results printed.

Please also check out the [list of documentation](https://github.com/io-tupelo/clj-template#documentation) in the project.

Answer (score 0):

the whole point of the task is to have the correct view of input and output data and create the transition form the former to the latter with small functions.

in your case i can see the following problems with the domain modelling:

1. your input employs two collections where items are connected by the index in the collection. This one is hard to manage and error prone, if you need to add/remove new movies. This probably should be a collection of something like `{:title "asd" :genre "ccc"}`.
2. your output has 3 different fields for wrong answers, which is also quite hard to manage in case you need more or less wrong variants shown (you would need to add `:wrong4`, `:wrong5` etc. Wrong answers should probably be a collection inside the answer entity.

i would propose the following shape of the input data:

```
(def data [{:title "Avatar" :genre #{"Fantasy" "Adventure" "Action"}}
           {:title "I Am Legend" :genre #{"Sci-Fi" "Horror" "Drama"}}
           {:title "300" :genre #{"Fantasy" "Drama" "Action"}}
           {:title "The Avengers" :genre #{"Sci-Fi" "Thriller" "Action"}}
           {:title "The Wolf of Wall Street" :genre #{"Biography" "Comedy" "Crime"}}
           {:title "Interstellar" :genre #{"Sci-Fi" "Adventure" "Drama"}}
           {:title "Game of Thrones" :genre #{"Fantasy" "Adventure" "Drama"}}
           {:title "Vikings" :genre #{"History" "Drama" "Action"}}
           {:title "Gotham" :genre #{"Crime" "Drama" "Action"}}
           {:title "Power" :genre #{"Crime" "Drama"}}
           {:title "Narcos" :genre #{"Biography" "Crime" "Drama"}}
           {:title "Breaking Bad" :genre #{"Thriller" "Crime" "Drama"}}
           {:title "Doctor Strange" :genre #{"Fantasy" "Adventure" "Action"}}
           {:title "Rogue One: A Star Wars Story" :genre #{"Sci-Fi" "Adventure" "Action"}}
           {:title "Assassin's Creed" :genre #{"Fantasy" "Adventure" "Action"}}
           {:title "Luke Cage" :genre #{"Crime" "Drama" "Action"}}])
```

every movie is a map including title and a set of its genre.

and as an output data shape i would propose the same shape enriched with the wrong answers field:

```
{:title "Gotham",
 :genre #{"Crime" "Drama" "Action"},
 :wrong #{"Fantasy" "Comedy" "Thriller"}}
```

(the good part is that these models share the same set of fields, so you can imagine some generic functions over the superset of them in future)

Here is how i would approach to the transformation part:

```
(defn make-question [max-wrong-answers all-genres item]
  (->> item
       :genre
       (clojure.set/difference all-genres)
       shuffle
       (take max-wrong-answers)
       set
       (assoc item :wrong)))


(make-question
 3
 #{"Fantasy" "Adventure" "Drama" "Crime" "Action"}
 {:title "The Avengers" :genre #{"Sci-Fi" "Thriller" "Action"}})

;; {:title "The Avengers",
;;  :genre #{"Sci-Fi" "Thriller" "Action"},
;;  :wrong #{"Fantasy" "Crime" "Drama"}}
```

so now you just have to create the stream of random questions based on the initial data:

```
(defn get-questions [data]
  (let [all-genres (reduce into #{} (map :genre data))]
    (repeatedly #(make-question 3 all-genres (rand-nth data)))))

 (take 3 (get-questions data))

 ;;({:title "Narcos",
 ;;  :genre #{"Biography" "Crime" "Drama"},
 ;;  :wrong #{"Fantasy" "Comedy" "Action"}}
 ;; {:title "Vikings",
 ;;  :genre #{"History" "Drama" "Action"},
 ;;  :wrong #{"Biography" "Adventure" "Crime"}}
 ;; {:title "Rogue One: A Star Wars Story",
 ;;  :genre #{"Sci-Fi" "Adventure" "Action"},
 ;;  :wrong #{"Biography" "Fantasy" "Comedy"}})
```